# How can a MS Teams admin install custom apps to their users so that I receive conversation_id of all their users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am building a custom app for MS Teams that sends Proactive chat messages to the users of each of the teams. When I give the app to the teams admin, they will publish the app, but I am not sure how the admin will install for their users, so that I receive conversation_id of all the users in their teams after it has been installed.
I am aware that it is possible through Graph API and is looking to eliminate the app installation through Graph Api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for an admin to do this using the Teams Admin section in the Microsoft 365 Tenant Admin screens. Specifically, you're wanting to set up something called "App Setup Policies". See here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies#create-a-custom-app-setup-policy

Using these policies, admins can pre-install the app, and can even pin it on the left menu. They can also choose to do this for all users, or just a specified group.

To be clear though, this will install the app to the users in a -personal- context - it will NOT install the app to any -actual- Teams / Channels or Group Chats - you'd need to use Graph for that, and even then it will only be able to install to -existing- Channels or Chats and won't automatically cover new ones added after that, if that's what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. By **-existing- Channels or Chats**, do you mean that the newer members in the team will not have the app installed, and thus have to be added manually (by admin) later?

Comment: You need to be clear on the difference between an app that has "personal" scopes versus on that has Team or Group Chat scope, as these are different. I've tried to cover both in my answer but that might be more confusing. To be clear - do you want the user to receive a _personal_ message, from a bot they have installed like into the "Apps" bar on the left of Teams, or do you want the proactive message to instead come into the Channel or Group Chat?

Comment: I want the proactive messages to be personal messages (like including the name of the person, and only to be sent to the person who hasn't completed their task), hence it should be personal scope, right? I believe this is not possible in Team or Group chat scope because other people who have already completed the tasks will also see the message.

Comment: To explain in more detail, the proactive messages are sent to each user who has not completed their tasks, and is sent weekly. The teams that want to add this feature has to signup on our website, and I believe they will be taken to the permission website to grant permission for several actions in the graph api.I want to eliminate the permission and graph api process if admin can install app for all their users, and we will be notified of the conversation_id, so as to send notification from our app weekly.

Comment: ok perfect, thanks for clarifying. In that case, to answer your question, the admin can select which users the policy would be applied to, or can apply it to -all- users in the organisation, current or future users.

Comment: Just to make sure, the conversation_id is sent when the app is installed by administrator, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. Your bot (which would be part of your app) will receive a `conversationUpdate` event which will include the user's details and the conversationId and Service Url you need for proactive messaging. See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition

Comment: I installed the app for users via `TAC -> Teams App -> setup policy` but did not receive conversationUpdate event. Then I removed the app from `TAC -> Teams App -> setup policy` and tried to add it again, then it shows me an error that I cannot save setup policies. Is there a time limit on this? or am I missing something here?

Comment: It takes a while for the setup policies to propagate, I think